# Como proteger um site de serviços antes do lançamento?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Não tenho experiencia nisso e estou para lançar um site de serviços e queria saber se o que tenho que fazer para proteger a minha idéia é a patente dela, registro de software ou registro de marca? Essas são as opções que aparecem no Instituto Nacional da Propriedade Industrial - INPI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sobre o [INPI](http://www.inpi.gov.br/):

A) O registro de marca vai proteger apenas o NOME ou LOGOTIPO, que você registrar.

B) O registro de software, vai proteger apenas o código fonte, que você deverá gravar em CD/DVD e enviar em formato PDF. Porém, se alguém escrever (ou reescrever) o código de forma diferente, não será caracterizada cópia do seu código.

C) A patente poderá ser útil se: ["[...] você inventou uma nova tecnologia, seja para produto ou processo"](http://www.inpi.gov.br/menu-servicos/patente/guia-basico-de-patente).

Eu faria o registro do software e se possível, faria também a patente (a ideia - caso seja realmente original).

Segue abaixo a legislação pertinente: importante lembrar que a maior parte das leis regem a propriedade industrial/intelectual no Brasil são REALMENTE muito antigas, pois nossos legisladores estão "muito ocupados com outras atividades":

- [Lei 9.609 de 1998](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Leis/L9609.htm) - Dispõe sobre a proteção da propriedade intelectual de programa de computador, sua comercialização no País, e dá outras providências.
- [Lei 9.279 de 1996](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Leis/L9279.htm). Regula direitos e obrigações relativos à propriedade industrial.

Boa sorte em seu empreendimento e espero ter ajudado!